# How to create a trigger to send email

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to create a trigger in SQL to send email to specific addresses. The outline is:

1. I have created a `select` that  returns an alert column indicating 1 if balance is low or 0 if it is not.
2. I need to create a `trigger` that if alert column is 1 it sends an email.
3. The `select` and `trigger` need to be executed once a week.

What could be the best way to accomplish this? Any guidelines would be helpful. I am using a Firebird database.

Comment: This seems to be a question that relates more to programming instaed of sql. Maybe you will get an answer when you rephrase the question and use other tags?

Comment: Hi, I  posted because I wanted to know if it was possible to do with SQL using trigger or else.

Comment: Why do you want to couple your application logic with your data base?

Comment: I just wondered whether it was possible and easier to write just one piece of sql that could select, identify 1 in the column, trigger and send an email, instead of writing side code in another language to process the sql result and send the email. I am curious about what it is possible to do in sql that i don´t  know.

Comment: I see. SQL does not support sending E-Mails, as far as I know. SQL ist not a programming language.

Comment: ok, thanks to your time to reply.

Comment: @MacOS technically he can create a DLL plugin to the server which can do anything, from formatting HDD to sending e-mails, but that would truly be a very bad idea. Making database engine threads freeze or crash due to external conditions, risking database corruption...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the database engine may *initiate* e-mail sending it should never *do* the sending itself.
Only some short (quick) and error-free actions should be done within the database server.

There should be another application/service/daemon running, which should be doing the e-mails based on the data prepared in SQL realm. The question is when this sender application should be triggered.

The database-agnostic way would be polling the database by scheduled time intervals, which traditionally nicknamed as "cron" actions, mentioned by Rajiv Shah. Once a minute or once a second or once an hour - by your choice.

A Firebird-specific way would be using `POST_EVENT <string constant>` command. It can be used instead of time-based polling or together with.

Here is the example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER POST_NEW_ORDER FOR SALES
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  POST_EVENT 'new_order';
END
```

https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-postevent

How your program would subscribe to those events would be dependent upon programming language and Firebird-accessing library. As far as i understand PHP would probably fit poorly there, as it is more tailored to run short scripts by daemons' requests, rather than being a continuously running daemon itself. Though perhaps PHP gurus can have it both ways. I also don't know if PHP has support for the Firebird events, it does not seem to be a priority for scripting language.

You can read more about Events by googling for `Firebird POST_EVENT`, among many links there will be for example those:

- [Is it possible to use arguments with firebird events :  POST_EVENT 'event_name' + string args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338077)
- https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/firebird-database-events-and-message-oriented-middleware/
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf

Comment: Thank you Arioch. You gave me a whole view on the problem.Nice :)

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull granted, if you really only need it "once a week" with no time pressure, then perhaps Rajib's cron-based approach is good enough and comes with least coding required. Basically you can do it as (maybe, for you) simple as coding a special WWW page, that can only be accessed from withing your own server and is 403-ed for outer world. Then set cron to use `wget` to fetch that page once a week, and make the page generator send the mails. The worms in the can would be to detect and mitigate "missed runs" like if the server had power outage in the very scheduled day.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [CRON](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) in the stack you are working with and check for column periodically and if satisfies your criteria send email.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, do you have a code example about this idea ? Thanks.

Comment: I meant to say better to do it in your backend then db itself. Decouple business logic from database.

Comment: Hi, got your idea. Maybe write a php script that will use the sql result to output the alert email...for example.

Comment: Yes If you are use PHP then do it in PHP itself.

Comment: PHP is typically called by WWW servers, meaning when there is no WWW visitors - `mod_php` would not get called.