# Send mail with trigger from Firebird 2.5

Tags: email, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

Is it possible to generate a trigger to send an email every time a record is inserted into a table? I am using Firebird 2.5.

Comment: Don't do it from inside Firebird. Make a separate out-of-FB application and notify it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a trigger to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957312/how-to-create-a-trigger-to-send-email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird itself doesn't provide anything for sending email out of the box. In Firebird 2.5, you can write a custom UDF (User-Defined Function) that allows you to send email. In Firebird 3.0 and higher you can also write a UDR (User-Defined Routine; the replacement for UDF).

For an alternative solution, see also [How to create a trigger to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957312/how-to-create-a-trigger-to-send-email).