# Is there a way to know if the Event Alerter is called locally or from other user, to avoid double refreshes?

Tags: firebird

I use Firebird 3 with IBDAC and try to use Alerter Event to refresh data from other user/users, is there a way to know if the Alerter is called locally or from other user, to avoid double refreshes?

It is a good feature to refresh data (mostly small lookup fields) when other user has changed over the network.

Code is like this:

```
procedure TdmTables.IBCAlerterEvent(Sender: TObject; EventName: string; EventCount: Integer);
begin

  If CompareText(EventName, 'Item_Category_Upd') = 0 Then 
    tbItems.Refresh;
end;
```

It's working fine, but the event is called locally and also on all clients.

Comment: I think it is not possible, i think if you do not want refreshing the whole table you have to make some kind of log table (or add "version" column to rows but that would not cover "row deleted" scenario) and let each client remember which log row it fetched last and only read newer log rows. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338077/is-it-possible-to-use-arguments-with-firebird-events-post-event-event-name

Comment: At first, "refresh" method doesn't do what you think and is useless here. At second, automatic refresh of a dataset on every event is a very bad idea: at some point it will trash performance and piss users off with frequent grid flickering. You'd better just enable "refresh" button to let user know that something has been changed since the data appeared on the screen.

Comment: ...and implement that refreshing in a separate transaction

Comment: Yes user13964273 you are right, its better to dot it visual like the refresh button, rather refreshing. Thank you both .