# How to print message in ISQL / IBExpert Sql tool?

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0, isql, ibexpert

I know that in SQL Server we can print message via operator PRINT, but PRINT doesn't work in IBExpert, and command OUTPUT too. Can someone help me?

[image]

I have this error when I run previous code:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual input or output, but post it as code formatted text.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm a beginner in writing questions on this site.

Comment: Since your message text is static you might consider using (abusing?) events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338077 and i guess one can try to use Win32 `OutputDebugString` API as an UDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird has no such feature. It is not possible to "print" or "output" messages in this way (nor does Firebird have a statement called `OUTPUT`<sup>1</sup>).

The only option you have in stored procedures is to return the message as the value of a return column. For triggers, there is no real option, though you could write things to a global temporary table and explicitly select from that GTT before transaction commit or something similar. However, that requires explicit action on your part to get the output.

---

<sup>1. The Firebird query tool ISQL has a command called [`OUTPUT`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-command-output), but that is purely for redirecting output of ISQL itself to a file.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I created some DebugLog table for writing information and now in my trigger I insert in table DebugLog date, time and message. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Nika should your `DebugLog` table retain the message if the transaction was rolled back, or should it cease to exist then ?

Comment: In my case, all I have to do is save the message. For me it is not important and that's why I think my table retain the message if the transaction was rolled back